# I am having trouble with a few javascript do while loops

Tags: javascript, do-while

I am writing a code guessing program to test the security of some iPhone passwords (This is not in anyway connected to anything illegal or is used to break into actual iPhones). The do/while loops just end all response once they occur and the last two lines don't print to the console.

```
print("Hi!");
print("I am a password security tester.");

var tries = 0

var guess1 = 0
var guess2 = 0
var guess3 = 0
var guess4 = 0

var guess = (guess1 * 1000) + (guess2 * 100) + (guess3 * 10) + guess4;

var password1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*9));
var password2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*9));
var password3 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*9));
var password4 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*9));

var password = (password1 * 1000) + (password2 * 100) + (password3 * 10) + password4;

print("This is the randomly genorated password: " + password);
print("And now begins the guessing");

do{
    guess1 + 1;
    tries + 1;
}while (password1 != guess1);

do{
    guess2 + 1;
    tries + 1;
}while (password2 != guess2);

do{
    guess3 + 1;
    tries + 1;
}while (password3 != guess3);

do{
    guess4 + 1;
    tries + 1;
}while (password4 != guess4);

print("Complete in " + tries + " tries");
print("The answer is: " + guess);
```

Comment: in your loops, you are not setting the variables, just adding 1 to them and doing nothing with the result. so you need `guess1 += 1;` et

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but the code used for generating the digits will give you values from 0 to 8 inclusive, not 9.  Math.floor always rounds down and Math.random always gives a number less than 1.  Assuming you want the full range of digits, that should be Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

Answer (score 3):

[Jacob Ewing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27157946/3187556) is correct, but another problem is that `guess` will still be 0 at the end, because it doesn't automatically update. You'll need to do:

```
var guess = (guess1 * 1000) + (guess2 * 100) + (guess3 * 10) + guess4;
```

Before:

```
print("Complete in " + tries + " tries");
print("The answer is: " + guess);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using a `+=` operator instead of just `+`

Saying `guess1 + 1` returns the value of `guess1 + 1`, but does not increment that value directly, so you get an infinite loop.

Comment: or using `guess1 = guess1+1` is more clear for a newbie.